# Godot 4 Merge polygons from tiles

Tags: c#, navigation, polygon, godot

I want create the navigation manually. I have a function to get polygons. But the function return polygon is not correct. The "obstacle" tile is still have inside the polygon.

```
public Vector2[][] GetCellsOutlines()
    {
        var grounds = tileMap.GetUsedCells(0);
        var arr = new List<Vector2[]>();
        foreach (var coords in grounds)
        {
            var objectTile = tileMap.GetCellTileData(1, coords);
            if (objectTile == null || !objectTile.GetCustomData("isObstacle").AsBool())
            {
                var size = getTileSize();
                var sizeX = new Vector2(size.X, 0);
                var sizeY = new Vector2(0, size.Y);
                var topLeft = tileMap.ToGlobal(tileMap.MapToLocal(coords));
                var topRight = tileMap.ToGlobal(tileMap.MapToLocal(coords)) + sizeX;
                var bottomRight = tileMap.ToGlobal(tileMap.MapToLocal(coords)) + sizeX + sizeY;
                var bottomLeft = tileMap.ToGlobal(tileMap.MapToLocal(coords)) + sizeY;
                arr.Add(new Vector2[] { topLeft, topRight, bottomRight, bottomLeft });
            }
        }
        return arr.ToArray();
    }
```

```
    public Vector2[] TilesPolygon()
    {
        var poly = new Vector2[0];
        var cells = GetCellsOutlines();

        var other_polys = new List<Vector2[]>();

        foreach (var cell in cells)
        {
            var merged = Geometry2D.MergePolygons(poly, cell);
            poly = merged[0];
            if (merged.Count > 1) other_polys.Add(merged[1]);
        }


        while (other_polys.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < other_polys.Count; i++)
            {
                var merged = Geometry2D.MergePolygons(poly, other_polys[i]);
                poly = merged[0];
                if (merged.Count > 1) other_polys.Add(merged[1]);
                other_polys.RemoveAt(i);
                --i;
            }
        }

        return poly;
    }
```

If I draw the polygons of tiles by GetCellsOutlines(), it is correct polygon includes the holes which is obstacle. But TilesPolygon() is wrong polygon.

```
public override void _Draw()
    {
        foreach (var item in GetCellsOutlines())
        {
            DrawColoredPolygon(item, Colors.Green);
        }
        // /DrawColoredPolygon(TilesPolygon(), Colors.OrangeRed);
    }
```

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Not the same thing, but this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67412060/402022